# Rx undefined error while using signalR Hubs

Tags: system.reactive, signalr, signalr-hub

I am trying to implement push notifications using signalR hubs. I have a sample code, which when I run, I get an error saying 
JavaScript runtime error: 'Rx' is undefined

This error comes in the dynamic signalr/hubs file.
I have added all the necessary Javascript references i.e., jquery, signalR and signalr/hubs.

What am i missing ?

My code looks something like this:

Global.asax file has this

```
public class Global : System.Web.HttpApplication
    {

        protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {


            RouteTable.Routes.MapHubs("~/signalr");


        }
```

My Hub is defined like this

```
 [HubName("HealthCheck")]
    public class MyConnectionClass : Hub
    {
        public static List<string> messages = new List<string>();

        public void GetServiceState()
        {
            Clients.updateMessages(messages);
        }

        public void UpdateServiceState()
        {
            messages.Add(DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss"));

            Clients.updateMessages(messages);
        }
```

And my client in javascript like this

```
 $(function () {
                // creates a proxy to the health check hub
                var healthCheckHub = $.connection.healthCheck;

                // handles the callback sent from the server
                healthCheckHub.updateMessages = function (data) {
                    $("li").remove();

                    $.each(data, function () {
                        $('#messages').append('<li>' + this + '</li>');
                    });
                };

                $("#trigger").click(function () {
                    healthCheckHub.server.updateServiceState();
                });

                // Start the connection and request current state
                $.connection.hub.start(function () {
                    healthCheckHub.server.getServiceState();
                });
            });
```

Also I have added all the necessary js references in the client.
I have picked this sample from [here](http://blog.devscrum.net/2011/12/getting-started-with-signalr-in-asp-net-mvc/) 
Is this enough or am i missing something ?

Thanks

Comment: Can you post a minimal code example that reproduces the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Given that the error is about Rx not being defined I'm wondering if you may have installed the wrong NuGet package.  It sounds like you installed [SignalR.Reactive](https://github.com/cburgdorf/SignalR.Reactive) instead.

I think [this](http://nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR) is the package you really want. (Note that this is a prerelease version and I think the package names changed quite recently so it's possible the tutorial you're following is slightly out of date, which may have been what's caused the confusion.)